# Controller Extension Error

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I have a VF page on a custom object and I am trying to create a button that will essentially mark a checkbox field as TRUE and save the record.  I created a controller extension and I have a Repeat element in my VF page.  However, when I try to save the page, I get the error:

> Error: Unknown property
>   'Campaign_Create_Request__cStandardController.Create_Case__c'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

**Controller:**

```
public class VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase{

public List<Campaign_Create_Request__c> CCR {get; set;}


//    private final Campaign_Create_Request__c myCase;
    public VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase(ApexPages.StandardController myController){
        CCR = new List<Campaign_Create_Request__c>();
    }

    public PageReference CreateCase() {

        CCR[0].Create_Case__c = true;
        insert CCR;
        return null; 
    }
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Campaign_Create_Request__c" extensions="VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase">

   <apex:form >
   <apex:repeat value="{!CCR}" var="CC">
```

Comment: Please provide the full visualforce page.

Comment: `Error: Unknown property 'Campaign_Create_Request__cStandardController.Create_Case__c'` looks like issue in you other part of code.

Comment: As Namfuak and Ratan said, We need a bit more of your page to figure it out

Comment: Thanks to both, I was missing a piece in my variable declaration that got rid of the error.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ratan & Sebastian, I spoke too soon.  I now get an error:

Error: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0
Error is in expression '{!CreateCase}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page vf_campaigncreate_view: Class.VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase.CreateCase: line 15, column 1

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You never added any element to your list and were trying to access it. That's why it was throwing the List out of bound exception.

Update your controller:

```
public VF_Controller_CreateCampaignCase(ApexPages.StandardController myController){
    CCR = new List<Campaign_Create_Request__c>();
    CCR.add((Campaign_Create_Request__c)myController.getRecord());
}
```